# how to display dates in french using php strftime?

Tags: php, locale

I am getting english results when I run that

```
    setlocale (LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8','fra');
    $french = strftime('%A', $time);
    echo $french;
```

I also tried with `setlocale (LC_ALL, "fr_FR");`

Any idea how to obtain french dates ?

Answer (score 0):

To display dates in French, I'll suggest you use

> setlocale() and strftime() functions.

Check out this reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php